# Unable to use variable in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a MySQL query to return a a number of rows with the following code:

```
<?php

$resultset1 = '0, 100';

$sth1 = $conn->prepare ("SELECT * FROM data1 ORDER BY name LIMIT '$resultset'");
$sth1->execute();

?>
```

This gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0, 100'' at line 1' in /home/search/Search/statement1.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /home/search/Search/statement1.php(8): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /home/search/Search/result.php(20): include('/home/search/Se...') #2 /home/search/public_html/session.php(93): include('/home/search/Se...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/search/Search/statement1.php on line 8

If I replace `'$reultset1'`, in the query, with `0, 100` everything works fine.

Comment: Someone help me understand: why would this question get voted down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query you were trying to execute looked like this:

```
SELECT * FROM data1 ORDER BY name LIMIT '0, 100'
```

The parameters to `LIMIT` should not be in quotes.

```
$sth1 = $conn->prepare ("SELECT * FROM data1 ORDER BY name LIMIT $resultset");
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace `'$resultset'` with `$resultset` (without the quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from the variable.  Or you can concenate the string.

```
$sth1 = $conn->prepare ("SELECT * FROM data1 ORDER BY name LIMIT " . $resultset);
```